# Is there is a other way to share the whole Android project including XML resource without exposure to the code

Tags: android, xml, jar, package

I need to pack my project into a jar for others to use. But when I run the program, it throws a lot of Nullpoint exception, the program can not find the correct R.id.
 One solution is to use the getIdentifier() replace R.id.
 the other is to use a public.xml.
 and use android stuido export a .aar file.

But I have too many R.id in the project, it's a lot of work to use first and second way. And project is developed by Eclipse, can not use aar file.Is there a other simple way.

Comment: Finally, I wrote a script to use the getIdentifier() replace R.id in class to solve this problem.